# How to customize the ImageButton style?

Tags: android, styles, material-design, android-styles, android-imagebutton

I am making a numeric keyboard.
[keyboard appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8los.png)

I have a problem with the decoration of the return button.
If I use ImageButton, then I get an indent from the top, as in the picture:

[button backspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQEPj.png)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- other buttons -->
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnPoint"
        style="@style/KeypadButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:text="."
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnNumber0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnNumber1" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnNumber0"
        style="@style/KeypadButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:text="0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnBackspace"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnPoint"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnNumber2" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnBackspace"
        style="@style/KeypadButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:text=""
        app:iconGravity="end"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnNumber0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnNumber3" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the style of the buttons

```
<!--  Keyboard  -->
    <style name="KeypadButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextView">
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/font_large_30</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/swatch_7</item>
        <item name="backgroundTint">@color/key_number</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ripple_bg</item>
        <item name="android:textAlignment">center</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
    </style>
```

If I inherit the ImageButton style, then I get padding around the button, which cannot be removed.

Please tell me how to properly design the backspace button.

[Link to the project](https://github.com/mertsalovda/Calculator-of-power/tree/develop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replace

```
 <style name="KeypadButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextView">
```

to

```
 <style name="KeypadButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the problem.

Comment: Не за что, можете отметить вопрос как решенный)